# add url parameters automatically to a given site

Tags: redirect, http

I need to automatically add some GET parameters when someone is typing a specific url from inside my LAN.
Example, you digit `www.example.com` and you will redirect to `www.example.com?variable=1`

I have an internal DNS, internal firewall (fortigate) and AD, if can help

Comment: Things would be easier if you had a webserver too.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I have...what would you seuggest?

Comment: Tell us which one, so you can receive some suggestions on how to solve your problem.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille apache or nginx, both. Btw I don't need a how to...can be some tips on how to follow the steps to achive that

Comment: I'd use an internal rewrite.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille that's what I was thinking but there is a catch. dns server pointing the official site to an internal web server that has a .htaccess which adds the url parameters to the official site? But every request form the clitn will be solved on the internal server not on the official one.

Comment: I don't know if it's your spelling, but you've lost me there.

Comment: Sorry for my english. Can you answer this question providing detailed infomations, so I can understand. thanks

Comment: No, I can't.  I do not understand your comment from 2 days ago.

Comment: Cannot you provide the answer to the original question? I think all the details are there